# Passing a templated smart pointer type as template parameter

Tags: c++, templates

I am trying to pass smart_pointer as a template parameter than use the type for dynamic casting  etc..

But there is one more catch smart_pointer can have many types like std::shared_ptr, boost::shared_ptr, std::weak_ptr so on.

So what I am trying finally is replace `typename SmartPointerType<DerivedClass>` with correct syntax :

```
template < typename SmartPointerType<DerivedClass> >
std::vector<SmartPointerType<DerivedClass>> filterByType()
{
    std::vector<SmartPointerType<DerivedClass>> newList;
    for ( int i = 0; i < iTerrainList.size(); i++)
    {
        SmartPointerType<DerivedClass> castedTerrain = Cast<DerivedClass>(iTerrainList[i]);
        if ( castedTerrain )
            newList.push_back(castedTerrain);
    }

    return newList;
}
```

"Cast<>()" accepts any type of smart pointer that I am interested btw.

I find out I can use something like

```
template <template <typename Type> class TemplateType>
```

But it didn't worked for with my c++03 compiler.

I know I can use ".get()" but I am curious how can I make it work without ".get()".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just let it work on any type:

```
template <typename DerivedClassPtr>
std::vector<DerivedClassPtr> filterByType()
{
    std::vector<DerivedClassPtr> newList;
    for ( int i = 0; i < iTerrainList.size(); i++)
        if ( DerivedClassPtr terrain = Cast<typename DerivedClassPtr::element_type>(iTerrainList[i]) )
            newList.push_back(terrain);

    return newList;
}
```

Here, the requirements on the template type are that it:

- Can be stored in a vector (so must be copyable).
- Has `element_type` (so raw pointers won't work, for better or worse; you could fix this with type traits implemented yourself in C++03).
- Is accepted by your `Cast()` function.
- Is usable in a boolean context.